# Error With array_search

Tags: php

I seem to have hit an error with array search. Below is my code.

```
$allowedTypes = array(
    'image/gif',
    'image/jpg',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png'
);
if(array_search("image/gif", $allowedTypes)) {
    print "true";
} else {
    print "false";
}
```

It always prints false. Even though image/gif is in the list of allowed types.

Answer (score 6):

[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns the index of the item in the array.  In this case, it's returning integer 0, which, when converted to bool, is false.

If you'd read the documentation, you'd have seen the following in a large red box:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

You must use:

```
if (array_search("image/gif", $allowedTypes) !== false) {
  // ...
}
```

Or, to simply tell if the array contains the item, you can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) which does return a simple yes/no in boolean form:

```
if (in_array("image/gif", $allowedTypes)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah ha! Makes perfect sense. I've used in_array() anyway, it seems to be a more logical function for this purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$allowedTypes = array(
    'image/gif',
    'image/jpg',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png'
);
if(in_array("image/gif", $allowedTypes)) {
    print "true";
} else {
    print "false";
}
```