# Problem with Array Search in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am not finding what might be the problem in my program.

I am having an array like this

```
$arr = array("1", "urgent", "4", "low", "15", "avg");
```

When i am searching this array using

```
$key = array_search("4", $arr);// Working
```

Its is giving me the index of that element;

But when i am searching for "1" it is not giving me any index.

```
$key = array_search("4", $arr); // Not working here - for searching "1"
```

What might be the problem.

Thank You

Comment: You might want to fix that second example. Also, what *is* it giving you? How do you determine it's "not working"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error With array_search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600597/error-with-array-search)

Comment: There are so many duplicates, *plus* the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) explicitly covers this case. With a huge red box.

Comment: @meagar: why to read documentation if there is SO [irony] ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Because it is good to understand programming, and not get others to do your work for you.

Comment: @meagar: the question you referenced is not actually similar, since there OP wanted to know whether element exists in array or not, but here perhaps OP wanted to know its index (not sure, but this wasn't clarified in the question).

Comment: @meagar: it was an irony! but to be clear, if all manual-reading-related will be removed from SO, there will left about 10-20% of current amount, not more. I bet.

Comment: @zerkms That would be ideal, in my opinion. The extremely trivial stuff doesn't belong here.

Comment: @meagar: try to open new topic in meta about adding new close reason "Too simple question" or "Manual-related question" then? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Those ideas have already been suggested in Meta.

Comment: @meagar: since there is no such statuses I could suppose that most of community and owners think that such questions are appropriate here... ;-)

Comment: @meagar: What defines "extremely trivial"? Not everybody on SO is a guru, that's why the site exists in the first place. Sure, it's written in the documentation, but the fact that searching for "problem with array search php" (a query for which most having the same problem will actually use) ranks first in Google, even before the manual, says it all. SO is a reference, even if the answer is "check the manual here and there", it's still useful and for that reason this kind of question belongs on SO in my opinion. At least in this case OP tried, unlike many others who go "will this work?".

Comment: @netcoder I disagree. The goal of Stack Overflow isn't to mirror the documentation of all languages in Q/A format. If a question is so trivial that it is clearly answered by the documentation, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @meagar: The goal of Stack Overflow is Q/A on programming. This is a programming question. Whether it is a documented behavior doesn't matter. 90% (if not more) of the questions asked here have documented solutions (whether on a public site or a old dusty book somewhere). There's no mention of triviality/documentation in the FAQ, therefore it's not forbidden nor discouraged to ask such questions. If you still disagree, then it's a Meta matter.

Comment: @netcoder There is no explicit rule saying that "How do I add two numbers in C++?" is a bad question, but it's still a bad question. There has to be a line where questions are too trivial for us to bother copy-pasting the documentation. All this aside, my bigger beef with this question is that it's a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://ideone.com/e1n3r Your code does work fine. It returns key == 0, which is the key, where "1" is stored.

To get the difference between 0 and `false` you should use `===` operator, or its contrary `!==`:

```
$arr = array("1", "urgent", "4", "low", "15", "avg");

$key1 = array_search("1", $arr); 
var_dump($key1 === false);  // false (value exists)
var_dump($key1 !== false);  // true (value exists)

$key21 = array_search("21", $arr); 
var_dump($key21 === false); // true  (value does not exist)
var_dump($key21 !== false); // false (value does not exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

array_search return key value of array.

```
    $arr = array("1", "urgent", "4", "low", "15", "avg");
    $key = array_search("4", $arr); 
   // give output is 2 which is key value 
    $key = array_search("1", $arr);
   //give output is 0 which is key value
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `0` is evaluated to `FALSE` in php.

so..

```
if($index = array_search("1",$arr)) {
    //will actually evaluate to false
}
```

In case you are using it this way and think it's not working because the conditional isn't technically failing, the value is evaluated as `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `$key` in thewrong way. `$key = 0` and now if you do boolean evaluation it will act as false. You should use something like `if($key >= 0)` or `if(is_int($key))`